# lookupTransform now not erroring as expected in tf python tutorial

Tags: ros, python, tf-tutorial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working through the Python version of the tf tutorial on page using Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

For the first example on page: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28Python%29 an error is expected when asking for a `lookupTransform` with time set to `rospy.Time.now()`.

The "chaser" turtle does not move, but no errors are reported. Can anyone else verify this? Perhaps the error is suppressed in newer versions of ROS?

Worked through the rest of the page and everything is working as expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243501/lookuptransform-now-not-erroring-as-expected-in-tf-python-tutorial/) by [dheater](https://answers.ros.org/users/27907/dheater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 216 on 2016-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it. In a previous step, we wrapped the `lookupTransform` call with

```
        except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException):
```

Removing `tf.ExtrapolationException` for the list of handled exceptions allows the error to be reported.

---

Originally posted by [dheater](https://answers.ros.org/users/27907/dheater/) with karma: 216 on 2016-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dheater](https://answers.ros.org/users/27907/dheater/) on 2016-09-10**:
Edited tutorial to reflect this.